# How to reproduce the embed of the discord API default 'help'?

Tags: python, embed, discord.py

I created a bot using the discord API in python.

But when i use an embed, i have no control over the width of it, and since i use them to create columns, sometimes one of them goes row and formatting is broken while the area does not even take up half the page.[The 4th column goes to the next row while the width of the embed does not exceed half the width of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE7I2.png)

Apparently, it is not possible to choose the width. However, the help command which is implemented by default is large, how can I do that?
[The default help uses what appears to be a much larger embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve3Ou.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default help command is just a code block, you can create one by adding 3 backticks to the beginning and end of your text.

```
Value 1         Value            4812
Value 2         Value            4812
Value 3         Value            4812
Value 4         Value            4807
Value 5         Value            4806
Value 6         Value            4803
Value 7         Value            4802
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll just miss being able to write the column headers in bold

Comment: Unfortunately code blocks disable Markdown parsing, you can only make the entire code block bold by adding ** around the code block.